# Area of the largest rectangle with sides parallel to $x$- and $y$-axes that can be inscribed in the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections

First off, I simplified the equation of the ellipse to get it to

$$9x^2 + 16y^2 = 144$$

And then did further simplification to get it in terms of:

$$y= \bigg(9 - \frac{9 x^2}{16}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

So I then plug in $y$ to the equation of the area of a rectangle:

$$A = xy = x(9 - \frac{9x^2}{16})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

And then I proceeded to differentiate the expression with respect to $x$ and derived:

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = (9-\frac{9x^2}{16})^{\frac12} + 9x^2\cdot(16(9-\frac{9x^2}{16})^{-1})$$

After I attempted to find the critical points of $\frac{dA}{dx}$, I multiplied both sides of the equation by:

$$16(9-\frac{9x^2}{16})^{-1}$$

And then got:

$$144 - 9x^2 + 9x^2 = 0$$

And this is where I knew all this work had been done wrong, as my relation of the area of a rectangle and the ellipse was wrong. Can anyone Show me the right way to start of the problem to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You didn't take your derivative correctly.  The second part of your product rule is pretty messed up.  The first thing is that the last exponent should be $-1/2$ not $-1.$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the area of largest rectangle that can be inscribed in an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240192/find-the-area-of-largest-rectangle-that-can-be-inscribed-in-an-ellipse)

Comment: [Search time approx six seconds](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=rectangle+inside+ellipse). You may prefer to use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210695/11619) as a dupe target instead. I don't remember what swayed my pick in 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Your differentiation wasn't correct......

$A = xy = x(9 - \frac{9x^2}{16})^{\frac12}$

$\frac{dA}{dx} = (9 - \frac{9x^2}{16})^{\frac12}+\frac{x}{2}(9 - \frac{9x^2}{16})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot -\frac{9x}{8}$

$\frac{dA}{dx} = (9 - \frac{9x^2}{16})^{\frac12}-\frac{9x^2}{16}(9 - \frac{9x^2}{16})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$